# User.objects.create_user() in django does not works

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, django-models, django-views

I have been trying to create objects using 'User' class in Django for entering my user details to database but it does not works. no records where created during the process. I also tried by creating my own models in models.py file of my app, it creates all the tables and the attributes given to the class are modifies to tabular columns in my database but still also the objects creation fails, no rows where created on the table. No errors were shown. Could you please explain the solution to my problem.

```
def user_signup(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_name = request.get.POST('username')
        email = request.get.POST('email')
        phone_no = request.get.POST('phone')
        pass1 = request.get.POST('pass1')
        pass2 = request.get.POST('pass2')
        
        user = User.objects.create_user(user_name,email,pass1)
        
        user.save()
        
        print('user created')
        
        return redirect('user_signin')
    return render(request,'signup_page.html')
```

This is the code that i have written it doesn't work.

Comment: Please use a *form*, don't process request data manually...

Comment: Do you use a custom user model?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
def user_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_name = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        phone_no = request.POST.get('phone')
        pass1 = request.POST.get('pass1')
        pass2 = request.POST.get('pass2')
        
        user = User.objects.create(user_name=user_name,email=email,phone_no=phone_no,password=pass1)
        # ---------- OR -----------
        user = User.objects(user_name=user_name,email=email,phone_no=phone_no,password=pass1)
        user.save()
        print('user created')
        return redirect('user_signin')
    return render(request,'signup_page.html')
```